# Problema com Actualização Textbox c#

Tags: c#

Tenho:

- 2 RadioButton
- 1 ComboBox
- 1 TextBox

O valor do `radiobutton` escolhido vai para a `TextBox` mais o valor da `Combobox`.

```
TextBox = RadioButton + Combobox
```

Porém, se eu mudar, o valor do `Radiobutton`, o `Textbox` não altera, está a alterar o valor da `Textbox` caso se mude de `Radiobutton` ou `Combobox`.

**Código**:

```
  private void combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radiobutton1.Checked && combobox1.Text == "Cerfificação (CER)")
        {
            textbox1.Text = "CER" + " SRV";
        }
        if (radiobutton1.Checked && combobox1.Text == "Desenvolvimento (DES)")
        {
            textbox1.Text = "DES" + " SRV";
        }
        if (radiobutton2.Checked && combobox1.Text == "Desenvolvimento (DES)")
        {
            textbox1.Text = "DES" + " CLI";
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo rápido aqui:

```
private void cmb1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Converte o item selecionado em um item do combobox
    ComboBoxItem item = (ComboBoxItem)cmb1.SelectedItem;
    // assim consigo pegar o valor dele
    string valor = item.Content.ToString();
//chk1 = radionButton ou CheckBox
// (chk1.IsChecked ?? false) pega o valor que seja diferente de false. pois o CheckBox possui 3 estados.

// faço a comparação se o checkbox está selecionado com o valor que foi selecionado.
if ((radio1.IsChecked ?? false) && valor.Equals("Valor 1"))
    txt1.Text = radio1.Content + valor;

else if ((radio1.IsChecked ?? false) && valor.Equals("Valor 2"))
    txt1.Text = radio1.Content + valor;

else if ((radio2.IsChecked ?? false) && valor.Equals("Valor 3"))
     txt1.Text = radio2.Content + valor;
}
```

Comment: Não amigo @MeuChapeu, assim não me dá...

Comment: Por que? Acontece algum erro?

Comment: @GodfatherSantana, fiz uma alteração no código, assim está funcionando somente quando você alterar no `combobox` se quiser alterar quando altera no `RadioButton` precisara ter um evento de `Checked` no `RadioButton` para alterar quando for feita uma alteração no `RadioButton`.

Comment: Amigo @MeuChapeu, preciso de ambas, ou seja, quando altera `RadioButton` e `Combobox`.

Comment: @GodfatherSantana, Sim só implementa o evento `Checked` do `RadioButton` e fazer as validações `(IFs)` no evento. como foi feito no evento do `ComboBox` quando é trocado a seleção.

Comment: Já consegui, obrigado amigo @MeuChapeu!